# How to pass variable to exec command in expect script?

Tags: shell, openssl, expect

The purpose of the script is to read an encrypted file ".pass" and decrypt the file using a PublicKey, and the decrypted output should be saved

```
puts $output
```

should show the decrypted password.

PublicKey will change every time based on my key generation logic, so I wanted it to be set as a variable

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set value "PublicKey"
set output [ exec sh -c {cat .pass | cut -d'&' -f1 | openssl base64 -d | openssl enc -d -rc2 -k "$value" } ]
puts $output
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tcl {braces} are like shell 'single quotes' -- no variable expansion is performed within.

You need to use different quoting:

```
set value "PublicKey"
set cmd "cat .pass | cut -d'&' -f1 | openssl base64 -d | openssl enc -d -rc2 -k $value"
set output [ exec sh -c $cmd ]
puts $output
```

Answer (score 0):

There are [typographic quotation marks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark) in your file - you need to instead use only `'` and `"` (straight quotation marks) to [quote strings](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes).